installer all the hard drives show up and I see no way to Deselect them
On an existing system with multiple drives, I want to install Debian on a SSD External boot drive.
When using the installer, it shows the other drives and I see no method to select the drives and say DO NOT TOUCH.
I am a little paranoid that the installer will write some thing to these drives.
Any Ideas?

The installer is working exactly as it is designed. It allows one to select a drive to which to install the OS. It doesn't have an option to choose disks to which one doesn't want to install it. It will indicate the drive that has been selected afterwards.
If you are concerned, then disconnect all of the drives to which you don't want to install Debian so that there is only one available. That will completely eliminate any possibility of accidentally installing to a drive that you don't want. Otherwise, just select the drive to which you want to install it and proceed.

Thanks but when using a machine with internal drives (NVMe), where disassembly of a machine to "disconnect" the drive is certainly a "negative customer impact feature".

@jwilleke You are not disassembling a machine. You are disconnecting a device. NVMe drives can be disconnected/removed and often are just as SATA drives are. How else would anyone replace one of them if needed such as for example, if it is defective or if you want to install a different one with more space? Instead of just repeating something that you've read, either disconnect the drive and install Debian or leave them as is and only select the drive to which you want to install Debian and proceed. This is simple and there is no reason to complicate it where it isn't necessary.

The Intel NUC has two internal NMVe Devices which requires disassembly.

It requires the case to be opened and a part to be removed which, as I stated, is done all the time. You don't any choice here because there is no method in the Debian installer to select drives to which one doesn't want to install the operating system. Deal with it. I can't state anything else without repeating myself so it's up to you.

And I cannot keep repeating myself either, it is a "negative customer impact feature".
And nearly impossible on some Laptops and other small devices.
There SHOULD be a better way!

You can either look at things in the way that they are or in the way that you think that they should be. You could have installed Debian many times over by now. You are basically just repeating something that you have read which isn't going to change anything. There is no way to do what you want as the installer for Debian doesn't allow it which is why you don't see the option there and it is not going to magically appear. You can either select the disk to which you want to to install Debian and proceed from there or do what I mentioned. Otherwise, you won't be able to install Debian.
